# Redirect stdout of a subprocess to stdin of 2 or more subprocesses

Tags: python, subprocess, named-pipes

Basically I want to learn how to use the `stdout` of one `subprocess` (say `proc1`) as `stdin` of 2 or more other `subprocess`es (say `proc2` & `proc3`) in python.

Hi,
I need to `zcat` a .gz file and use the output sent to `subprocess.PIPE` for both `cksum` (unix utility) and to line count.

I can do it in bash like this...

```
[hashroot@dev_server 12]$ zcat ABC_C_TPM_26122014.data.gz | tee >(wc -l) >(cksum)| tail -2
2020090579 112180
586
```

I want to do the same in python.

As soon as I do this...

```
>>> import subprocess
>>> import os
>>> fl123 = 'ABC_C_TPM_26122014.data.gz'
>>> pqr123 = subprocess.Popen(['zcat', fl123], stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
>>> subprocess.check_output(['cksum'], stdin=pqr123.stdout)
b'4286000649 256100 \n'
```

Now the `PIPE` is empty so how will I get line count till I don't do `zcat` again.

I can very well do it by running zcat twice in subprocess, and redirecting the first `zcat` output to wc -l and the second `zcat`'s output to `cksum`. But `zcat` is disk IO based and is slow. So I want to avoid it.

Answer (score 4):

A simple way to implement the `tee` command in Python is to write to the subprocesses manually:

```
import gzip
from subprocess import Popen, PIPE

# zcat ABC_C_TPM_26122014.data.gz | tee >(wc -l) >(cksum)
with gzip.open("ABC_C_TPM_26122014.data.gz", "rb") as input_file:
    wc = Popen(['wc', '-l'], stdin=PIPE, bufsize=1, close_fds=True)
    cksum = Popen(['cksum'], stdin=PIPE, bufsize=1, close_fds=True)

    line_count = 0
    for line_count, line in enumerate(input_file, start=1):
        wc.stdin.write(line)
        cksum.stdin.write(line)
    wc.stdin.close()
    cksum.stdin.close()
wc.wait()
cksum.wait()
print("Line count in the parent: %d" % line_count)
```

If the lines in the input can be large then you could read the input in chunks: `chunk = input_file.read(chunk_size)` instead of line by line (`b'\n'`).

Comment: >>> from subprocess import Popen, PIPE
    >>> import gzip
    >>> 
    >>> with gzip.open("cbp12co.csv.gz", "rb") as input_file:
...     wc = Popen(['wc', '-l'], stdin=PIPE, bufsize=1, close_fds=True)
...     cksum = Popen(['cksum'], stdin=PIPE, bufsize=1, close_fds=True)
...     line_count = 0
...     for line_count, line in enumerate(input_file, start=1):
...             wc.stdin.write(line)
...             cksum.stdin.write(line)
...     wc.stdin.close()
...     cksum.stdin.close()
... wc.wait()
  File "<stdin>", line 10
    wc.wait()
     ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
>>>

Comment: save the code to a file. Copy-paste does not work for multiline code in an ordinary Python REPL