# Popen: Sending stdout from one process to the stdin of two processes

Tags: python, popen

Basically, as the title says, I need to send the output from one process to the input of two processes. Here's a simple code example of the idea:

```
from subprocess import Popen, PIPE

input = Popen(['python', 'input.py'], stdout = PIPE)

proc1 = Popen(['python', 'print.py'], stdin = input.stdout)
proc2 = Popen(['python', 'print.py'], stdin = input.stdout)

proc1.communicate()
proc2.communicate()
```

When this code runs, `proc1` eats the input so from the input process so `proc2` doesn't get the information.

Comment: you cannot do this. You can only pipe the output to _one_ process, as pipe consumes the data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you cannot do this. You can only pipe the output to *one* process, as pipe consumes the data.

*but* you can read all output from process, and run other processes with this output as the argument of `communicate`.

```
from subprocess import Popen, PIPE

input = Popen(['python', 'input.py'], stdout = PIPE)
contents = input.stdout.read()

proc1 = Popen(['python', 'print.py'], stdin = PIPE)
proc2 = Popen(['python', 'print.py'], stdin = PIPE)

proc1.communicate(contents)
proc2.communicate(contents)
```

This isn't going to run in parallel obviously, unless you thread both `proc1` & `proc2` `Popen` calls. And the first process will have to run completely first.

Another possibility would be to feed inputs to both processes without using `communicate`:

```
from subprocess import Popen, PIPE

proc_in = Popen(['python', 'input.py'], stdout = PIPE)
proc1 = Popen(['python', 'print.py'], stdin = PIPE)
proc2 = Popen(['python', 'print.py'], stdin = PIPE)
for line in proc_in.stdout:
  proc1.stdint.write(line)
  proc2.stdint.write(line)

proc1.wait()
proc2.wait()
```

in that case everything runs in parallel. Each time an output is produced from first process it is fed to both processes, in real time.

now realizing that the question is a duplicate of [Python: Redirect stdout of a subprocess to stdin of 2 or more subprocesses](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27740689/python-redirect-stdout-of-a-subprocess-to-stdin-of-2-or-more-subprocesses). The answer is maybe too tailored to the question and complex. Leaving that one here.

Comment: This is exactly what I need. Thanks so much!

Comment: now I realize that this is a duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27740689/python-redirect-stdout-of-a-subprocess-to-stdin-of-2-or-more-subprocesses